# How would you generate the Magento Layout XML outside of Magento?

Tags: layout, magento

I want to be able to provide template, block details from the layout file generated by Magento.   the same information which can be seen if you install Alan Storm's excellent layoutviewer and print out the all the xml to screen.  (The Package Layout is what I am after, which is a large XML file that contains every possible layout configuration for a particular Magento install.)

I have been struggling to get this data from a script which i am running in the application directory alongside the index.php file.

How can I get the full layout XML in an xml document without installing any custom module installation?

Comment: Are you looking for the current page layout, or the entire package layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and easiest way I can think of getting the XML layout is by writing a Magento extension that gets the info and presents it or exports it programmatically. Otherwise, you will have to recreate the Magento logic of combining all the XML files, etc. which will result in larger code base.

Comment: I want the script to be something which can be installed by one file, otherwise I would just use Alan Storms Layout Viewer module.

Comment: I want the script to be something which can be installed by one file, otherwise I would just use Alan Storms Layout Viewer module.  I want the same info from package viewer but in a way which could be setup on a staging environment without installing modules.  However, I think maybe this could be impossible for me without some more suggestions from the community!

Comment: In the end I created my own script which gets this information.  Thanks for your discussion.

Answer (score 3):

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->load("default")->asString();
```

This piece of code will give you layout xml for given handle, still there exists need to scan layout files to find all handles to generate full xml.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it but at first glance I would think it should be

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getXmlString()
```

Comment: Nice try, and useful contribution for others, but this just builds the layout in readiness for blocks to be added to it.

Comment: How would I build the xml to describe all the blocks and templates that magento would need to run?

Comment: Sorry, I guess that only works for the page it's used on, and then only after `loadLayout()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
use 'Configviewer' and 'Layoutviewer'  
http://www.abc.com/index.php/index/index?showLayout=package
http://www.abc.com/index.php/index/index?showLayout=handles
http://www.abc.com/index.php/index/index?showConfig=true
```